# How to modify url in lighttpd config

Tags: lighttpd

I've a problem with my lighttpd setup. Here is where the problem begins:

```
server.document-root = vhosts_dir + "/" + server.name + "/wp"
```

Inside that directory are all files. Now, on this site is an image which has an url like

```
http://example.com/wp/uploads.....
```

Inside `lighttpd` this will translate to

```
`/var/www/vhosts/example.com/wp/wp/...
```

Unfortunately I cannot remove the `wp` part from the `document-root` :(

So I tried to rewrite this by removing one of the `wp`s as follows

```
url.rewrite-once = (
  "^(.*)/wp/(.*)$" => "$1/$2"
)
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to have zero effect, nothing seems to be modified. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to create a symlink wp -> . inside /var/www/vhosts/example.com/wp/

Another is to use lighttpd mod_alias to map requests to /wp to the document-root:
    `alias.url = ( "/wp/" => "/var/www/vhosts/example.com/wp/" )`

https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModAlias